# element type is invalid expected a string

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded my application to SDK 35 and got the following error :

> element type is invalid expected a string

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Start from './screens/Start.js'
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    Start: {
        screen: Start
    },
 });
const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default App;
```

Comment: This may happen if you do not write anything in component. Please add some code in component and then export that component and then use it.

Comment: example please ?

Comment: https://github.com/gokulkrishh/React-Native-Sample/blob/master/index.ios.js add this to your component and replace name with your component. And one more thing replace last line with `export default YourComponentName`

Comment: Post the Start screen source and check  if Start export default or may be remove .js extension